# How to Pass String parameter to cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to pass a String parameter to my cypher query. but I am getting the error.
e.g.

```
 String ner="Jon";
  String ADD_MEMBER_QUERY = "CREATE (a:person{ name: $ner }) RETURN a.name";
        session.run(ADD_MEMBER_QUERY);
```

I am getting error

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Expected parameter(s): ner
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Expected parameter(s): ner

Comment: `Expected parameter(s): ner` means that you have to pass parameter with name `ner`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, obviously.  The question is HOW to do that.

Comment: I already pass the parameter ner. it is a syntax issue.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-cypher .        I find this artical but does not know about export commond

Answer (score 0):

The `run()` method call can accept an additional parameter for query parameters after the String query itself, and this can be `Map<String, Object>` or a `Record` or a `Value` object.

See the interface [StatementRunner](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html), which is extended by both Session and Transaction.

It will also be worth reviewing the [sessions and transactions section](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/sessions-transactions/) of the driver documentation for examples and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can add paramters when calling the `run()` method:

```
String ner="Jon";
String ADD_MEMBER_QUERY = "CREATE (a:person{ name: $ner }) RETURN a.name";
session.run(ADD_MEMBER_QUERY, Values.parameters("ner", ner));
```

or

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("ner", "Jon");

String ADD_MEMBER_QUERY = "CREATE (a:person{ name: $ner }) RETURN a.name";
session.run(ADD_MEMBER_QUERY, parameters);
```